# Custom repo path

Tags: git, gitlab

So I get the following url from gitlab for a newly created project

`git@gitsource:kellye/calendar-tool-of-doom.git`

That gives me a back a 'does not appear to be a git repository error'

So on a hunch I tried this

`git@gitsource:repositories/kellye/calendar-tool-of-doom.git`

and it worked fine.

I'll note that I changed the `repos_path` in gitlab.yml and config.yml(in git-shell) to a raided folder `/source/repositories/` instead.

Any ideas how I can get that url to be correct, or fix my problem?

Also I made a symbolic link from /home/git/repositories to /source/repositories, so it's pulling the beginning `repositories` path pieces from that symbolic link.

That means that when I do a git pull, the root directory is the `/home/git` directory...something isn't set up right and I'm not sure what it is.

I tried even putting a `cd /source/repositories` into my `.profile` `.bash_rc` and `.ssh/config` and that didn't help either.

I've since moved the raid to `/home/git/repositories` and put all my files there, and updated all my config files and it still has the root set to `/home/git` instead of `/home/git/repositories`

That isn't a problem, what the problem is is the fact that *inside* of gitlab, it shows the url as `git@gitsource:kellye/amazon-bucket-loader.git`. All I care about is that it is correct, so even if it showed `git@gitsource:repositories/kellye/amazon-bucket-loader.git` instead I wouldn't care.

I also have a bug report with them...I guess we'll see who is snappier https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/3755

Comment: With all the moving you were doing, it's possible not everything is pointing where it should. Have you tried removing the repo and adding it again in Gitlab?

Comment: @Duotrigesimal Thanks, but still the same result

Comment: So, my gitlab.yml file says `# REPOS_PATH MUST NOT BE A SYMLINK!!!` right above the repos line, so that explains your earlier trouble.

Comment: This is the default setting: `repos_path: /home/git/repositories/`. Is that what your current setting is?

Comment: `ight above the repos line, so that explains your earlier trouble` I read that, but that wasn't a problem, I did that to check the paths.

Comment: @Duotrigesimal Yes that's what my repos_path is set to in both gitlab and gitlab-shell config files

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29700/discussion-between-duotrigesimal-and-kelton52)

Comment: Does the problem occur with a brand new repo that doesn't share the name with any previous repos? (Shows wrong url in Gitlab, but works by adding `repositories/`.)

Answer (score 0):

On the server, take a look at the /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys file.  Make sure the entry starts with command set to the gitlab-shell executable; like this:

`command="/home/git/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-shell key-2",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa .......`

You should not need to include the repositories directory in the SSH path.

Comment: Yeah that's what my authorized_keys file looks like. I didn't modify that at all, and gitlab seems to be able to write and modify the file just fine.

Comment: it looks like this `command="/home/git/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-shell key-2",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa AAAA(rest of the key)`

Comment: Like I was mentioning, I can hit it by adding repositories to the start of the url, but inside of the UI it shows the clone url without the word repositories